# SQL LEFT JOIN where clause with IN comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, where-in

May have inadvertently stumbled onto a good SQL test question.

- I have a table with let's say ~100 usernames.
- I have a set of 10 possible usernames { aname, bname, cname, dname, ... }

If I do:

```
SELECT user.username FROM user WHERE user.username IN ('aname', 'bname', 'cname',...);
```

I get a list of usernames selected for, minus the ones not found in the table, grand.

What I actually want, is a list of the ones NOT found in the table.

If the `WHERE...IN` clause list was a table, I'd just `LEFT JOIN` it onto the user table and filter for `NULLs`.

Is there a way to do this without making a temp table and left joining that to the user table? I guess, sort of a left join of the user table to the `WHERE...IN` clause?

I've never done or seen it, but perhaps it exists.

Comment: yey maybe you need not in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a derived table and a `left join`:

```
SELECT l.name
FROM (SELECT 'aname' as name UNION ALL
      SELECT 'bname' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'cname' UNION ALL
      . . .
     ) l LEFT JOIN
     user u
     ON u.username = l.name
WHERE u.username IS NULL
```

Comment: We have a winner!

Comment: I did run into a "mixed collations" error.<br/>
I added a BINARY cast to the compare.  


`SELECT l.name  
FROM (SELECT 'aname' as name UNION ALL  
      SELECT 'bname' UNION ALL  
      SELECT 'cname' UNION ALL  
      SELECT 'dname'  
     ) l LEFT JOIN  
     user u  
     ON BINARY u.username = BINARY l.name  
WHERE u.username IS NULL`